# Difference between 〜ておく and 〜っぱなし

Tags: usage

I was wondering, what the difference is between 〜ておく and 〜っぱなし?  For example, how is the sentence お皿を洗いながらお水を出しっぱなしにしました。different from お皿を洗いながらお水を出しておきました。? Thanks.

Comment: Related:  [What is the difference in terms of grammar between ～かける　and　～っぱなし?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5860/78) and [What is the difference in terms of grammar between きり　and　っぱなし?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5855/78).

Comment: Someone can correct me if I'm wrong because this is just the feeling I get, but it's always seemed to me that っぱなし meant something that was "left" carelessly or even though it shouldn't have been, while ておく indicates a deliberate action made with consideration for the future.

Answer (score 1):

These two phrases are totally different, and please see other questions for the general meanings.

～ておく ≒ do something in advance / in preparation for something. (Maybe you left the place after that, but it's not necessary)

- [What's the meaning of 〜ておきます?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12964/5010)
- [What does the "~ておく" mean in "任せておく"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5216/5010)
- [What exactly is おく doing in 聞いておく?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2997/5010)

～っ放【ぱな】しにする

- [What is the difference in terms of grammar between ～かける　and　～っぱなし?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5860/5010)
- [What is the difference in terms of grammar between きり　and　っぱなし?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5855/5010)

---

> お皿を洗いながらお水を出しっぱなしにしました。

This means you didn't turn off the water *while* you were doing the dishes. A typical response to this would be "Oh, please don't do that next time, let's save water."

> お皿を洗いながらお水を出しておきました。

This is a bit strange sentence, but a typical response to this would be "Wait, what do you mean? Maybe the water is still turned on? Stop it!" It's because the sentence sounds somewhat like "While I was doing the dishes, I didn't forget to turn on the water in advance", as if you had some other purpose you didn't mention.